# "registration_ids" field is not a JSON array (Firebase)

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am facing problem with Firebase "registration_ids". When I send the request from Rest Client i get the successful response.

```
{"multicast_id":4650719213012935695,"success":2,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1468837777484579%214918aff9fd7ecd"},{"message_id":"0:1468837777484484%214918aff9fd7ecd"}]}
```

But when I call same php script from my Android application it gives me error in the response. (I got the response in Charles Proxy)

```
"registration_ids" field is not a JSON array
```

Here is my php script

```
function fetchFirebaseTokenUsers($message) {       
    $query = "SELECT token FROM firebase_tokens";
    $fcmRegIds = array();
    if($query_run = mysqli_query($this->con, $query)) {         
        while($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
            array_push($fcmRegIds, $query_row['token']);
        }
    }

    if(isset($fcmRegIds)) {
        $pushStatus = $this->sendPushNotification($fcmRegIds, $message);
    }
}

function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

    ignore_user_abort();
    ob_start();

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'data' => $message,
    );

    define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'AIzaSyC.......VdYCoD8A');

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization:key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );      

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false)
        die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());

    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
    ob_flush();
}
```

Comment: Could you include your Android code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used `to` rather than sending array of Firebase tokens as `registration_ids`. Cause `registration_ids` having the limit of 1000 number of firebase tokens only https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref.

```
function fetchFirebaseTokenUsers($message) {       
   $query = "SELECT token FROM firebase_tokens";
   $fcmRegIds = array();
   if($query_run = mysqli_query($this->con, $query)) {         
      while($query_row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        array_push($fcmRegIds, $query_row['token']);
      }
   }

   if(isset($fcmRegIds)) {
      foreach ($fcmRegIds as $key => $token) {
         $pushStatus = $this->sendPushNotification($token, $message);
      }
   }
}

function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

   ignore_user_abort();
   ob_start();

   $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

   $fields = array(
     'to' => $registration_ids,
     'data' => $message,
   );

   define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'AIzaSyC.......VdYCoD8A');

   $headers = array(
      'Authorization:key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
   );      

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   if($result === false)
      die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());

   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
   ob_flush();
}
```

Comment: This will loop upto 1000 for 1000 users.. not a good approach at all

Comment: I don't recommend this solution. It does unlimited POST requests in a very short time. You could get on some firewall blacklists with this solution for spamming.

Answer (score 4):

If you Used `registration_ids` you need to passed data in array as follow:

**PHP**:

```
$fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => array($registration_ids),
        'data' => $message,
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

If registration_ids is just one Token as stated at
https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref
you should use the field 'to'.

FCM requires registered_ids to be a JSON Array with indexes starting from 0. 
I have the same error because the indexes where not these. I solved it using the PHP function array_values.

```
function sendPushNotification($registration_ids, $message) {

   ignore_user_abort();
   ob_start();

   $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

   //FCM requires registration_ids array to have correct indexes, starting from 0
   $registration_ids = array_values($registration_ids);

   $numTokens = count($registration_ids);
   if($numTokens == 1){
      $fields = array(
        'to' => $registration_ids[0],
        'data' => $message,
      );
   }elseif($numTokens > 1){
      $fields = array(
        'registration_ids' => $registration_ids,
        'data' => $message,
      );
   }

   define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', 'AIzaSyC.......VdYCoD8A');

   $headers = array(
      'Authorization:key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
   );      

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

   $result = curl_exec($ch);
   if($result === false)
      die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());

   curl_close($ch);
   return $result;
   ob_flush();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar scenario where I had to create a GCM group for user's registration tokens & that error occurred. I figured it out later that i was not following corrent JSON format mentioned on f[ire-base](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group)

**Solution:**

Create a model

```
public class tempo {
        public string operation {get;set; }

        public string notification_key_name { get; set; }

        public List<string> registration_ids { get; set; }
    }
```

then serialize it

```
  var hmm = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

and make a post call to google.