# Send firebase push notification to multiple users not working -php

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send `push` `notification` to multiple devices using below `PHP` script.when i send `notification` to one device ,it's working.but not working for multiple devices.

```
protected function pushNotification($reg_id){

      define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'AAAAgUh9ZSQ:APA91bEjQ2nO3Po9_-T_kNey4q3Eizcoc3gLsD04Bjh0KYXQu_33O2gpLBvmMV_DtbE3xP2evZ1Dwki6WRqgqu8ZYhOG2CYi-6Wpxq2CLy3SQPb1nD6QkzwNN0249pt-H2mAgB8L-sjm' );
      $registrationIds = array($reg_id);          
          $msg = array
                  (
                     'body'     => 'Hey! You have a new order in queue',
                     'title'    => 'New Order Receieved',
                     'icon' => 'myicon',/*Default Icon*/
                     'sound' => 'mySound'/*Default sound*/
                  );
        $fields = array
                (
                    'to'        => $registrationIds,
                    'notification'  => $msg
                );
        $headers = array
                (
                    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
                    'Content-Type: application/json'
                );

            $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
                curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
                $result = curl_exec($ch );
                curl_close( $ch );
                error_log("Result ".$result) ;

    }
```

Comment: Do a `print_r($reg_id);` And add what it displays

Comment: it's showing 3 id's   `["f61Nw1_JSI0:APA91bHRYNd806t4VrF-WTRo7C5LDF2P1SinfyNFEDX4E5tANAseEbB5VseF65FBfTKSdSEg6e4Hqm96rdV1tJGibBRbAIjkIhuhzFzgF1w9nkfgxYbGAof3Acm7as6NMZvQb3gqHw0X","fqUSY7KD8qo:APA91bG3k76J464KK0PODzu04hKSIEsF0YJBFZk_anbb_sfjXCJJ9mw0zPEMx2eebU9snJdyTJ9x7m7ij3Tb_GOkNnTC-qEKT_TLRufJI0rIpwczCiwHOTyoMNEvhEAw5Jzz2YV5GBnw","cID4ill2OSo:APA91bG1CETvtL8TvbEc51QOkQ_WQKEDzw7uvgloy8JWYLN_510YPWG-Lkrgzg9i9cendwTjvXVxYW9XMsg9_VpI1rOiA2z-K8MV7VHakAmHvv9ZrAylWPXP1YMLJGPTk9MXgHGwQk3p"]`

Comment: This post solved my issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38435097/registration-ids-field-is-not-a-json-array-firebase

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your use of `to` in `$fields`. `to` is to be used only when you have an individual `String` FCM ID. If you want to send notifications to an array of FCM IDs (which is your case), you must use `registration_ids` in place of `to`. Please note that you can only pass an array of size lesser than 1000 at a time in this operation.
For more information, https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref .